# How to split the values of each row of a Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a `Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox` which has the values:

1. CSCI 5200 Software [FALL 2013]
2. CSCI 5200 Design [FALL 2014]

Now I need to split each value before I insert it into to the database. For example, the first value should be split into CSCI, 5200, Software and FALL 2013.

I tried this:

```
$course = $this->getValue(self::ELEMENT_COURSES);
foreach ($course as $item) {
    foreach($item as $key=>$value) {
        echo $value."\n";
    }
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand, but as there is no answer yet. :)
In your values ​​available (option value) if possible, you should put a separator and then use the side php [`explode` method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0):

There is still not clarity in your question. But what you wanted is I think, you want to explode those options into the array like,

```
$course = $this->getValue(self::ELEMENT_COURSES);
$finalResult = array();
$counter = 0;
foreach ($course as $value) {
    $session = explode("[", $value);
    $sessionResult = rtrim($session[1], "]");
    $testArray = explode(" ", $session[0]);
    unset($testArray[count($testArray) - 1]);
    $finalResult[] = array_merge($testArray, array($sessionResult));
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($finalResult);
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result your answer as,

> Array (
>
> > > [0] => Array
> > >               (
> > >                   [0] => CSCI
> > >                   [1] => 5200
> > >                   [2] => Software
> > >                   [3] => FALL 2013
> > >               )
> > >
> > > [1] => Array
> > >               (
> > >                   [0] => CSCI
> > >                   [1] => 5200
> > >                   [2] => Design
> > >                   [3] => FALL 2014
> > >               )
> >
> > )

I hope this is what you wanted.